# About split (Python function)

Tags: python, function, split

My question is about split function

I have a tuple:

```
name = 'test_1_1', 'test_1_2', 'test_1_3-4-5'...
```

I want to get to something like this:

```
['test_1_1', 'test_1_2', 'test_1_3', 'test_1_4', 'test_1_5']
```

How could I do that?

Comment: hi welcome : please  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Your variable seems to be a *tuple*, and your output isn't valid at all. Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is pretty invalid but,

Does this work for you:

```
names = 'test_1_1', 'test_1_2', 'test_1_3-4-5'                                        

res = [] 
for name in names: 
    if '-' not in name: 
        res.append(name) 
        continue 
    parts = name.split('_') 
    for sub in parts[2].split('-'): 
        res.append(f'{parts[0]}_{parts[1]}_{sub}') # This is what makes sense to me but maybe you want the following: 
        # res.append(f'{parts[0]},{parts[1]},{sub}')



print(res)
```

output:

```
['test_1_1', 'test_1_2', 'test_1_3', 'test_1_4', 'test_1_5']
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `string` is indeed a `tuple`, you can use:

```
import re

name = 'test_1_1', 'test_1_2', 'test_1_3-4-5'
new_name = [re.split(r"[_-]", x) for x in name]
# [['test', '1', '1'], ['test', '1', '2'], ['test', '1', '3', '4', '5']]
```

Or, and because I didn't fully understand your question, you may need:

```
new_name = [re.sub(r"[_-]", ",", x) for x in name ]
# ['test,1,1', 'test,1,2', 'test,1,3,4,5']
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/e30a35d6fa)